# When calling RavenDb store.DatabaseCommands.GlobalAdmin.CreateDatabase() the call hangs

Tags: asp.net, ravendb, nancy

The project that I am currently working on is using RavenDb as an embedded datastore, while attempting to call out to make sure that the database exists in the store, I am finding that it hangs.

```
        var docStore = new EmbeddableDocumentStore()
            {
                DataDirectory = "Data",
            };

        docStore.Initialize();

        // Check to make sure that the database exists
        bool bcDatabaseExists = docStore.DatabaseCommands.GlobalAdmin.GetDatabaseNames(1024).Contains(DatabaseName);
        if (!bcDatabaseExists)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> settings = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            DatabaseDocument databaseDocument = new DatabaseDocument()
            {
                Id = DatabaseName,
                Settings = 
                {
                    { "Raven/DataDir", "~\\Data" }
                }
            };

            try
            {
                docStore.DatabaseCommands.GlobalAdmin.CreateDatabase(databaseDocument);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.Error(ex);
            }
        }
```

However when I hit the CreateDatabase call the process just hangs without any notification. I wanted to check to make sure I wasn't using the call incorrectly, or if there was a better call.

Any thoughts or suggestions that you can offer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What build are you using? And in what environment?

Comment: The above code works for me in a Console application using 3.0.3660 but as the post is tagged with 'nancy' I guess that's what OP is using. I'm having a hard time testing this with Nancy atm...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the question has nothing to do with NancyFX, probably you need [EnsureDatabaseExists](http://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.0/csharp/client-api/commands/how-to/create-delete-database#ensuredatabaseexists---extension-method) method. It will create the database, if it's not there yet.

Comment: Not sure why EnsureDatabaseExists works and CreateDatabase doesn't but this solved my problem... Thanks.